# PowerBI ZSCORE from a measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I'm trying to calculate ZSCORE basen on a measure created in DAX.

Measure would be:

```
Me1 = (CALCULATE(SUM('Data'[Amount]),'Dim1'[Name]="SALES") + CALCULATE(sum('Data'[Amount]), 'Dim1'[Name2]="COST")) / CALCULATE(SUM('Data'[Amount]),'Dim1'[Name]="SALES")
```

This is giving me the percentages by period.

Now my goal would be to calculate the Zscore of that measure, but I do not know the way to do it from a measure.

I have tried by creating a variable when creating the formula but it says "parameter is not the correct type":

```
Z-Score_new =
var calc = (CALCULATE(SUM('Data'[Amount]),'Dim1'[Name]="SALES") + CALCULATE(sum('Data'[Amount]), 'Dim1'[Name2]="COST")) / CALCULATE(SUM('Data'[Amount]),'Dim1'[Name]="SALES")
return
IFERROR((((CALCULATE(SUM(calc), FILTER(ALL('Data'[Date]), 'Data'[Date]= Max('Data'[Date]) )))) - AVERAGE(calc)) / STDEV.S(calc), BLANK())
```

Any idea or any suggestion of how I can get the calculation?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution by creating a calculate table using DAX:

```
Tabla =
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS('TableDim2'[Period],CROSSJOIN('Data','TableDim1','TableDim2','TableDim3'),
"Colum1", IGNORE(CALCULATE(SUM('Data'[Amount]),'Dim1'[Name]="SALES")),
"Column2", IGNORE(CALCULATE(sum('Data'[Amount]),'Dim1'[Name2]="COST")))
```

So now I could create a new column such as:

```
FinalMeasure = ((Tabla[Gross1]+Tabla[Gross2])/Tabla[Gross1])
```

Which allows me to finally get the Zscore measure:

```
Z-Score = IFERROR((((CALCULATE(SUM(Tabla[FinalMeasure]), FILTER(ALL(Tabla[Period]), Tabla[Period]= Max(Tabla[Period]) )))) - AVERAGE(Tabla[FinalMeasure])) / STDEV.S(Tabla[FinalMeasure]), BLANK())
```